# for instruction acting not like expected

Tags: java, for-loop

here's the code which I don't quite understand:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (i = 1); i++)
            System.out.println("FOR " + i);
```

I expected this code not to show anything, but instead it outputs 'FOR' one time.

I was thinking that i < (i=1) should compare the value of  i with the result of the assignment i=1 which is 1 -> so 1<1 which is false -> exit the loop without showing anything.

Maybe the way this comparison is made is different than I understand it. Thank you!

Comment: And why would you want to do this?

Comment: just ran into this by mistake and was surprised by the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i < (i = 1)
```

This will be evaluated as: -

```
0 < (i = 1)  -->   0 < 1  --> true, so for loop executes
```

On next run, when `i++` is executed and `i` becomes `2` (Since, `i` was `1` from the `(i = 1)` assignment on the previous run of loop.)

So, `i < (i = 1)`

evaluates to: -

```
2 < 1 --> false.
```

So, for loop exits.

**Note: -** In your `condition part (i < (i = 1))`, before the assignment (i = 1) happens, the LHS has already been evaluated to be 0, and stored in memory. So, it will remain 0. Its all about the order of evaluation. So the assignment `i = 1` will not affect the value of expression on LHS.

Comment: The problem is why i doesn't became 1 when it's reaching the point (i=1). Then will be 1<1 which is false. Remember i is the same i as the one before '<'

Comment: @wxyz.. No. It doesn't work like that. Before the assignment `(i = 1)` happens, the LHS has already been evaluated to be `0`. So, it will remain `0`. Its all about the order of evaluation. The expression once evaluated doesn't change its result.

Comment: So, the change made to `i` in `(i = 1)` will not be reflected to `i` on LHS, because the evaluated value of `i` on LHS has already been stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're true.

i < (i = 1) is the problem cause the assignation (i = 1) is a boolean eguals at true: 1

Comment: Wut Wut Wut?? What do you want to say? Please explain clearly.

Comment: i = 1 is an assignation, if an assignation is done on an argument, it is considered like a Boolean: if the assignation works, then true; if there is an error, it's false.

Comment: @Napsteur.. No it's not like that. An assignment never returns boolean. See my answer for what is happening.. Also read my comment there. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking that i < (i=1) should compare the value of i with the result of the assignment i=1 which is 1

yes, it compares it with what you are expecting. But you initialize `int i = 0`, thus having `0 < 1` which is `true`.

Comment: sure, but if it compares i with the result of the assignment i=1, then also i should be 1 now, so it should compare 1 with 1

Comment: See Rohit's Answer, he explains it greatly.